# HTML API popstate prevent ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with `popstate`, Basically my code works really well. I perform an AJAX request and pushState. The problem comes up when I hit the back button on the browser. The whole page will request AJAX again. As you know Github is using this method also but when we hit back button it will not request AJAX again. how does Github do that? This is my code :

```
function loadProducts(dataPage) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: test.php, 
        data: {page : dataPage}, 
        dataType: "html",
        cache: true,
        success: function(checks) {
            $(".ajaxpage").html(checks).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
}; 

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if (event.state != null) {
        var pop = event.state;
        loadProducts(pop.dataPage)
        document.title = pop.dataPage;  
    }
};

$('#product').on("click", ".paging a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    history.pushState({
        dataPage: $(this).attr('href')
    }, null, $(this).attr('href')); 
    loadProducts($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

i try to remove "loadProducts(pop.dataPage)" but the page did not show previous page that should be. only the URL had change.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You call `loadProducts` `onpopstate` and that makes an Ajax request. If you don't want to do that, then just don't do it.

Comment: i try remove it. but the page not showing the previous page that should be? nothing change. only the URL?

Comment: You have to get the data you want to display from *somewhere*

Comment: what did u mean somewhere? i try console.log(event.state) : it brings the object result { dataPage : 2 }   can i use this to make an  html output?

Comment: Unless the data you want to display on the page in the number "2", not really. By somewhere, I mean that you can't conjure up the text you want to display from nowhere. You have to get it from somewhere. One place that it exists is at the end of that Ajax request you want to get rid of. If you don't want to get it from there then you have to get it from somewhere else.